# iOS Present Viewcontroller getting black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying present ViewController I have created with StoryBoards:

```
 AuthViewController *authViewController = [[AuthViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authViewController];
    UIViewController *vc  = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] rootViewController];
    [vc presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But getting it with black screen. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alloc init `AuthViewController` does not mean that will create a view layout for controller.

Here view controller does not load its view that's why you are getting black screen. Use storyboard object and identifier of view controller to load its view.

Specify storyboard identifier in Storyboard of `AuthViewController` controller.

Add `Storyboard ID` and  mark `true` for `Use Storyboard ID` option like in below image:

[image]

Now get `AuthViewController` controller object using below code:

```
AuthViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AuthViewController"];
```

Answer (score 4):

You may refer to the snippet below for storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
AuthViewController *authViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"**YOUR_STORYBOARD_ID**"];
[authViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:authViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the ViewController for `AuthViewController` present in `Storyboard`? If yes, then you should pass it a `Storyboard ID` and should initiate your `AuthViewController` in this manner:

```
AuthViewController *authViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"_STORYBOARD_ID_"];
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the class, for example AuthViewController in the storyboard was a simple UIViewController, and in my swift class it was a UITabBarController. That's why it did not render anything.

Silly mistake, but I hope I can save some time for someone.